# Are there any free (or cheap) structured log viewers that will connect to Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-table-storage, serilog

I'm using Serilog in a few azure function apps.  It writes the logs to azure table storage, which is great but very limited and cumbersome for viewing the logs in case of problems. There are lots of logs and the structured logging framework would be awesome to take advantage of.

I know of Seq and a few others but it requires SQL Server.  Are there any that can just connect to Azure Table Storage? Or do I have to employ an on-prem sql server or other database just to view logs?

Comment: Just a note regarding Seq, it can use an SQL Server, but doesn't require one (in most environments its enough to have local disk storage available).

Comment: Azure storage explorer is not meeting your needs?